# Problems getting Ksoap2 client to talk to PHP based webservice

Tags: java, php, soap, wsdl, ksoap2

I'm having issues getting ksoap2 clients on a PC and Android to properly talk with a PHP webservice. I have tried both PHP's included libraries and nusoap and non of it works.

Forgot error. Both the Android and PC client give a org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException
but the messages are different. PC for instance gives *PI must not start with xml*

Here's the Code for my PC client.

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.*;

public class client {



    public static void main(java.lang.String args[]) {
        final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/writegpsdata";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "writegpsdata";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/";
        final String URL = "http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios.php";

        SoapObject rpc = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHOD_NAME);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        rpc.addProperty("writegpsdataRequest","A1,E1,E1,AT333AT333,9055627513,2012-02-02 02:02:02,2012-02-02 02:02:02,-454545.343434,434343.232323,A334A334A334A443X,1000000,3434");


        env.bodyOut=rpc;
        env.encodingStyle = SoapSerializationEnvelope.XSD;

        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        ht.debug = true;

        try {
            ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, env);

            System.out.println(ht.requestDump);

        }
        catch(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException ex2) {
            System.out.println("Error" + ex2.toString() );
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            String error = ex.toString();
            System.out.println("Error: "+ error);
        }


    }
}
```

Here's my PHP Server Code. THere is communication the function writegpsdata works but the client errors on the server response.

```
<?php
// submitGPS is a soap server which writes GPS data to a mysql database.
// requires the writegpsdata.inc file which contains the required function
// uses submitGPS.wsdl file for defining soap service

require_once ("writegpsdata.axios.inc.php");
//require_once ("lib/nusoap.php");

ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled","0"); //disabling WSDL caching
$server = new SoapServer("http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios.wsdl");
$server->AddFunction("writegpsdata");
$server->handle();
?>
```

For good measure, here's the wsdl file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="submitAxios" targetNamespace="http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/">
  <wsdl:message name="writegpsdataRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="writegpsdataRequest" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="writegpsdataResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="writegpsdataResponse" type="xsd:string"/>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="submitAxios">
    <wsdl:operation name="writegpsdata">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:writegpsdataRequest"/>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:writegpsdataResponse"/>
    </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="submitAxiosSOAP" type="tns:submitAxios">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="writegpsdata">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/writegpsdata"/>
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/" use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios/" use="encoded"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="submitAxios">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:submitAxiosSOAP" name="submitAxiosSOAP">
      <soap:address location="http://secure.g4apps.com/submitAxios.php"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that my include function writegpsdata had some extra characters being or end (outside php tags) that I couldn't see in eclipse. I copied the contents, deleted the file and pasted it in a new file and this error when away. Though I'm still having issues with my android client. I may post another question later.